Repl + Node + Prisma ORM OpenSSL issue
I am experiencing issues related to usage of Prisma ORM with Replit to seed my db, whenever I run the command npm run dev , I get the following error.
Prisma cannot find the required libssl system library in your system. Please install openssl-1.1.x and try again.
runner@e4d694f9ada7:~/node-prisma-repl-hello-world$ npm run seed

> nodejs@1.0.0 seed
> tsx prisma/seed.ts

PrismaClientInitializationError: 
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation in
/home/runner/node-prisma-repl-hello-world/prisma/seed.ts:13:17

  10 async function main() {
  11   // Create sample users
  12   const users = await Promise.all([
→ 13     prisma.user.create(
Unable to require(`/home/runner/node-prisma-repl-hello-world/node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node`).
Prisma cannot find the required `libssl` system library in your system. Please install openssl-1.1.x and try again.

Details: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Mn.handleRequestError (/home/runner/node-prisma-repl-hello-world/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:121:7638)
    at Mn.handleAndLogRequestError (/home/runner/node-prisma-repl-hello-world/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:121:6663)
    at Mn.request (/home/runner/node-prisma-repl-hello-world/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:121:6370)
    at async l (/home/runner/node-prisma-repl-hello-world/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:130:9633)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at main (/home/runner/node-prisma-repl-hello-world/prisma/seed.ts:12:17) {
  clientVersion: '6.0.1',
  errorCode: undefined
}

package.json -
{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "tsx src/index.ts",
    "seed": "tsx prisma/seed.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^6.0.1",
    "prisma": "^6.0.1",
    "tsx": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.10.1",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  }
}

Repl link - https://replit.com/login?source=org-repl&goto=%2Ft%2Fsequence%2Frepls%2Fnode-prisma-repl-hello-world
Steps to reporduce -

npm install
npx prisma migrate deploy
npm run seed

Thanks for any help in advance.
I have already tried -

Installing openssl with config.nix and dependencies panel.
Connecting with a AWS DB URL
Connecting with a supabase postgres DB
Updating prisma from 5.6.0 to 6.1.0 (LTS)

Expectation -
For the seeding to execute on my remote DB URL

I solved the issue by installing openssl at the dockerfile
take a look at the command below is implemented for all the staging step
RUN apk add --no-cache openssl

check my dockerfile below
FROM node:20-alpine As development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add --no-cache openssl
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY --chown=node:node . .
RUN npx prisma generate
USER node

FROM node:20-alpine As build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add --no-cache openssl
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node --from=development /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node . .
RUN npm run build
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN npm ci --only=production && npm cache clean --force
USER node

FROM node:20-alpine As production
RUN apk add --no-cache openssl
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/public ./public
CMD ["node", "dist/main.js"]

